# UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout header misalignment

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uikit, uicollectionviewcompositionallayout

I have created a custom layout based on `UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout` that presents each section's items in a panel or card...

[image: Panel without a header]

...here the blue area is a `NSCollectionLayoutDecorationItem` that is passed to the section via its `decorationItems` property. This *background* item has its own content insets that inset it from the collection view bounds (*the grey area*) and the section has its own content insets to inset it within the panel. The purple section is 3 full width items (*cells*).

This all works as expected.

However, when I try to add a header to each section using `boundarySupplementaryItems`, the header (*red*) appears to ignore the section's content insets, but the section does size itself as though it's properly positioned...

[image: Panel with a header]

...the header pins itself to the top of the section, but the section height increases by the height of the header + the insets.

Here is the code I'm using to generate the layout...

```
let itemSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1.0), heightDimension: .fractionalHeight(1.0))
let item = NSCollectionLayoutItem(layoutSize: itemSize)

let groupSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1.0), heightDimension: .estimated(44.0))
let group = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.vertical(layoutSize: groupSize, subitems: [item])

let headerSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1.0), heightDimension: .estimated(44.0))
let headerItem = NSCollectionLayoutBoundarySupplementaryItem(layoutSize: headerSize, elementKind: "header", alignment: .top)

let panelBackgroundItem = NSCollectionLayoutDecorationItem.background(elementKind: "PanelBackground")
panelBackgroundItem.contentInsets = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: 4.0, leading: 8.0, bottom: 4.0, trailing: 8.0)

let section = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: group)
section.boundarySupplementaryItems = [headerItem]
section.contentInsets = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: 11.0, leading: 15.0, bottom: 11.0, trailing: 15.0)
section.decorationItems = [panelBackgroundItem]

let configuration = UICollectionViewCompositionalLayoutConfiguration()
configuration.interSectionSpacing = 4.0

let layout = UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout(section: section, configuration: configuration)
layout.register(PanelBackgroundView.self, forDecorationViewOfKind: "PanelBackground")
```

Can anyone advise on how I can get the header to position itself properly – just above the first item in the section, and respecting the content insets that have been set?

Comment: `estimated(44.0)` implies you are using internal autolayout constraints. What are they?

Comment: Also, what if you use NSCollectionLayoutSupplementaryItem instead?

Comment: @matt For the cell, I'm justing pinning a view to the edges of the `contentView`, and then setting its `height` to `44.0`. For the header, it's just a single constraint setting the `height` to `44.0`. These are simply placeholders for now and will be replaced with actual content (labels etc.) once I get the layout displaying correctly.

Comment: `NSCollectionLayoutSection.boundarySupplementaryItems` expects an array of `NSCollectionLayoutBoundarySupplementaryItem` and not `NSCollectionLayoutBoundaryItem`, so that's not an option I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1):

@Rafael, I post the answer here because the comment doesn't allow enough characters. This is taken from WWDC 2019's advanced collectionView layout :

```
func createLayout() -> UICollectionViewLayout {
    let itemSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1.0), heightDimension: .fractionalHeight(1.0))
    let item = NSCollectionLayoutItem(layoutSize: itemSize)
    
    let groupSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1.0), heightDimension: .absolute(44))
    let group = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(layoutSize: groupSize, subitems: [item])
    
    let section = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: group)

    
    let header = NSCollectionLayoutBoundarySupplementaryItem(layoutSize: NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1.0), heightDimension: .estimated(44)), elementKind: SectionHeadersFootersViewController.sectionHeaderElementKind, alignment: .top)
    header.contentInsets = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: 20, leading: 0, bottom: 20, trailing: 0)
    let footer = NSCollectionLayoutBoundarySupplementaryItem(layoutSize: NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1.0), heightDimension: .estimated(44)), elementKind: SectionHeadersFootersViewController.sectionFooterElementKind, alignment: .bottom)
    section.boundarySupplementaryItems = [header,footer]
    section.contentInsets = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 10, bottom: 0, trailing: 10)


    let config = UICollectionViewCompositionalLayoutConfiguration()
    config.interSectionSpacing = 10
    
    let layout = UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout(section: section, configuration: config)
    return layout
}
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OOR9D.png)

Answer (score 0):

One way to work around, you can set contentInset.top to zero and using UICollectionViewCompositionalLayoutConfiguration.interSectionSpacing. Then the sectionHeader gonna be right above the first cell, and we also can configure the spacing among sections.

[spacing among section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IKOzG.png)
[using configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zGnJ0.png)

Comment: Can you add a code example (not in an image)?